# denied: requested access to the resource is denied cuando intento enviar mi imagen Docker a mi repositorio DockerHub

Tags: docker

Tengo imágenes de un código que hace resúmenes de archivos de documentos (pdf, docx ...). He creado una imagen Docker que quería compartir en línea en Dockerhub. Pero extrañamente estoy recibiendo rechazado con un acceso denegado

```
remplacement@remplacements-MacBook-Pro SugiPerso % docker images
REPOSITORY                       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
google-drive-stats               latest    3ee6041a35da   2 hours ago    7.99GB
silverchair/google-drive-stats   latest    3ee6041a35da   2 hours ago    7.99GB
silverchair/summarize            latest    3ee6041a35da   2 hours ago    7.99GB
silverchair/summarizer           latest    3ee6041a35da   2 hours ago    7.99GB
<none>                           <none>    0fd8ba0a03d0   2 days ago     8.77GB
docker/getting-started           latest    289dc403af49   2 months ago   46.5MB
remplacement@remplacements-MacBook-Pro SugiPerso % docker push silverchair/summarize:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/silverchair/summarize]
b3e8d2260244: Preparing 
f23ef5b31c37: Preparing 
7b23b0f1ac1c: Preparing 
525da3ba2310: Preparing 
f6f8f61b9120: Preparing 
2546a271e121: Waiting 
646584c2f409: Waiting 
cfb461ef999f: Waiting 
416936900c68: Waiting 
0a39acbc2a98: Waiting 
2b6d33d15c9f: Waiting 
edf70074bd40: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Por lo tanto, yo soy silverchair! Y hicé el login.

Aqui esta la manera por la cual hice el login:

```
(venv) remplacement@remplacements-MacBook-Pro SugiPerso % docker login                                              
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded

Logging in with your password grants your terminal complete access to your account. 
For better security, log in with a limited-privilege personal access token. Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/access-tokens/
```

He intentado verificar especificando mi nombre de usuario, pero no puedo iniciar sesión aunque estoy seguro de mi contraseña (es la que utilizo para hub.docker.com):

```
(venv) remplacement@remplacements-MacBook-Pro SugiPerso % docker login -u silverchair
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Comment: +1 por el nickname Silverchair :)  PD. No es evidente cómo hiciste login en docker. Por favor, indícalo en la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alfabravo :))))) ¡Que grupo de rock ! Lo añadí enseguida